# How can I have straight contourlines in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I am plotting values with `imshow`, and I want to have one contourline at a certain value. However, `pyplot.contour()` uses some kind of interpolation which causes the contourlines to be diagonal around the point. How can I make sure that the lines are exactly lined up with my rectangular boxes (so only horizontal and vertical lines)?

(Anyone who wants to reproduce the picture I've got, the values are uploaded [here](http://textuploader.com/xj50))

A picture of the data looks like this:
[image: Contourlines]

produced with this code:

```
pyplot.imshow(KS_imshow, extent = [5. ,8., 0., 22., ], origin='lower', interpolation='nearest', aspect='auto', cmap = 'Blues', vmin = 0., vmax = 1.)
cbar = pyplot.colorbar()

CS2 = pyplot.contour(ri,phii,KS_imshow,levels=[0.5], colors='r')
cbar.add_lines(CS2)

pyplot.show()
```

The variables `ri`, `phii` and `KS_imshow` are in the linked document.

Comment: please post the code to reproduce the figure

Comment: @hitzg Added it. It is nothing weird, just `imshow` and `contour`.

Comment: I was not expecting anything weird. But I would like to just copy/paste and *run* your code. Whats the file format that you linked? What are the `--`s?

Comment: It is plain text, so it is probably possible to do something with `ri= *first line*`, et cetera. The `--` are numpy's masked values, because `KS_imshow` is a masked numpy array. The cmap doesn't make very low values white enough, especially when printed.

Comment: ok and how do you expect me to load this data (without writing a specific parser?). Your example should be simple to run for people who are willing to help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `imshow` creates "pixels", but the underlying data are just points (at the centers). Thus `contour` does not know anything about the image which `imshow` creates. However, you can create a similar image by upscaling the original data and then use `contour` on that. It is certainly a hack, but it achieves what you want. There remains a problem at the edges though and I'm not sure how to solve that.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage

# data ranges
xr = [5., 8.]
yr = [0., 22.]

# pixel widths
x_pw = np.diff(xr) / (KS_imshow.shape[1])
y_pw = np.diff(yr) / (KS_imshow.shape[0])

# plot the image
plt.imshow(KS_imshow, extent=xr+yr, origin='lower', interpolation='nearest',
        aspect='auto', cmap='Blues', vmin=0., vmax=1.)
cbar = plt.colorbar()

# upscale by a factor of 50 (might be an issue for large arrays)
highres = scipy.ndimage.zoom(KS_imshow, 50, order=0, mode='nearest') 

# correct the extent by the pixel widths
extent = np.array(xr+yr) + np.array([x_pw, -x_pw, y_pw, -y_pw]).flatten()/2

# create the contours
CS2 = plt.contour(highres, levels=[0.5], extent=extent, origin='lower',
        colors='r', linewidths=2)
cbar.add_lines(CS2)

plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

However, just to show a threshold of 0.5, I would suggest to customize the colormap instead of using a contour line:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

blues = plt.cm.Blues(np.linspace(0,1,200))
reds = plt.cm.Reds(np.linspace(0,1,200))
colors = np.vstack((blues[0:128,:], reds[-129:,:]))

i = np.linspace(0,1,256)
r = np.column_stack((i, colors[:-1,0], colors[1:,0]))
g = np.column_stack((i, colors[:-1,1], colors[1:,1]))
b = np.column_stack((i, colors[:-1,2], colors[1:,2]))
d = dict(red=r, green=g, blue=b)
mycmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap('mymap', d, N=256)

plt.imshow(KS_imshow, extent=[5, 8, 0, 22], origin='lower',
        interpolation='nearest', aspect='auto', cmap=mycmap,
        vmin=0., vmax=1.)

cbar = plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! It certainly is exactly what I want. Sorry for not having a directly runnable code available when I asked the question, and thanks again for putting so much effort in it. I'm not entirely sure how it works (probably that a rectangle has a size of 50x50 pixels in this figure picture), but it does the trick

Comment: I see the edit you made. It is indeed nicer with two different colormaps above a certain threshold. However, I want to compare different fields, and view how good they resemble each other. When I will use different imshows over each other it will be invisible to view this.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the nice answer by @hitzig I present some code that makes it simpler to draw straight contour lines. However, the underlying principle is exactly the same.

All we need are

- the extent of the data ...
- and [`np.kron`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html)

Then we can scale up our data using `big_data = np.kron(data, np.ones((factor, factor)))` and draw the contour lines using the `big_data` array. We make sure that the size of the image stays the same by passing the extent of the original data.

Example:

```
# Make up some data
data = np.zeros((10, 20))
data[2:4, 2:8] = 1 + np.random.random((2,6))

# Extent of the data into x and y directions
# (left, right, bottom, top)
extent = [0, 20, 0, 10]

# Plot the data a few times. Each time, the contours
# get drawn based on "enlarged" data to some factor
enlargement_factors = [1, 2, 10]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(enlargement_factors), 1)

for i, fac in enumerate(enlargement_factors):
    # Draw the data
    im = axs[i].imshow(data, origin='lower', aspect='auto', extent=extent)

    # Scale the data up (enlarge) ... or leave equal if fac==1
    big_data = np.kron(data, np.ones((fac, fac)))

    # Draw the contour lines of the data
    axs[i].contour(big_data, levels=[0.5], extent=extent, colors='w')
    axs[i].set_title('Enlargement factor: {}'.format(fac))

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image: code output, straight contour lines if high scaling]